# building unique bid site

Tags: php, open-source, lamp

i have a customer that want to build site of unique bid like :
http://us.dubli.com/Unique-Bid__unique-bid_show.html

i want to build it in LAMP environment.

i do not have an experience in bid sites

my question is :
what important issues do i need to take in advance while building site like this.

is there any open source existing  system , that i can use ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important factors are **causality** between bids, bid closing and **time** being accurate across all systems.

"is there any open source operating existing system , that i can use ?" leads me to believe you need to read up a bit on web development. The question doesn't make sense in the context that you use it ... because **L** in LAMP is **Linux**.

**L** - Linux operating system
**A** - Apache web server
**M** - MySQL Database
**P** - PHP/Perl/Python

There are many permutations of this setup such as WAMP, LAMM and others. I would also suggest you look at things like **Google App Engine** or some **hosted rails** solution to ease the amount of administration then migrate if it is a success.

**Edit**
If you want an existing system, things like **Drupal Auction** http://drupal.org/node/67918 exist. Might not be robust, but you can probably find others for other frameworks/CMS

Answer (score 0):

> is there any open source operating existing system , that i can use ?

Linux?

**EDIT** to reflect change in OP

perhaps you want something like this: http://www.invisionize.com/market/v-83/Auction-System-eBay-Clone--IBMafia-/ (note: not free)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to plan the whole thing from the OS upwards? If you are unsure what OS to use, I'd suggest you don't manage the hosting side of things until you are a bit more proficient in systems administration. There are crap loads of 'how tos' on building up a LAMP server though.

By 'bid site' do you mean like eBay? Just an auction site? How will members manage payments? How many auctions are you expecting (For selecting the right DBMS for the site)? What language will you use? There are a lot of things to think over before jumping into a potentially large project like this.

Hope that helps

Comment: He linked to a site he wants to copy. It's basically gambling bordering on fraud.

Comment: @Michael - +1 ... But I don't like to judge :P